# 2 Dynamic @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, linq

Есть два `@Html.DropDownListFor`.
Как через **JavaScript и Ajax** сделать чтобы после выбора значения в первом `@Html.DropDownListFor` автоматически по определенному условию менялись значения во втором `@Html.DropDownListFor`. Использую язык **C# (ASP.NET MVC)**

Comment: Опишите подробнее. Данные сразу загружены в свойствах модели. Или нужно за ними ходить на сервер? Учитывая упоминания Ajax, предполагаю второе.

Answer (score 0):

Вы дали слишком мало информации, что именно у вас не получается.

Допустим, имеются два DropDownList. У одного `id` равен `first`, у второго - `second`.
Навешиваем на первый обработчик события, в котором делаем ajax-запрос.

```
$('#first').change(function () {

    var value = $(this).val();
    var second = $('#second');

    $.ajax({
        url: "Home/GetData",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "value": value },
        success: function (data) {

            second.empty();

            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                second.append($('<option></option>').text(item));
            });

        }
    });

});
```

В случае успешного получения данных заполняем ими дропдаун.

Естественно, укажите правильный url, на который посылается запрос и его тип (POST, GET).